# How do I access labels on a form from multiple classes?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm very much a beginner in C# and forms and my exercise is to create a window that writes the current time in different formats.
However I'm stuck at trying to access the different labels of the form from different classes.

The layout would look something like this:
[clocks layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W98Ah.png)

So for now I'd like a standard clock, a clock that writes the time in binary and a clock that spells the time out with letters.

What I wanted to do was to create a class for each of these that would calculate what's needed and then tell the labels what to show.

So I created a form in Program.cs with the main function:

```
Form1 myForm = new Form1();
```

This might have been unnecessary as it already has some pre-generated code which starts Form1 (this is also a part I don't really get; doesn't it need to be instantiated?):

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

What I tried with the normal clock class:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Clocks
{
    public class NormalClock
    {
        public NormalClock()
        {
            myForm.lNormalClock.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        }
    }
}
```

However, this couldn't access the form's labels.

So my question is this: how do I access one form's different labels from different classes?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: From where (which class) are you instantiating `NormalClock` - from `Form1`?

Comment: I've made some changes and tried to do that in Program.cs, however NormalClock can't access myForm's label

Comment: ok I've made some changes and now it's in Form1.cs, seems to work ok now, but the code looks kinda inelegant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need reference to your instance of Form (myform) to have chance to access it's labels, but I'm afraid unless you change it, it is protected or private by default so you won't be able to do it anyway, unless you change its access modifier which is not the best idea.

Best course of action is make any class that is depending on something (dependency) to pass that something in constructor.
For you it would be passing the instance of Label to your clock class.

```
    namespace Clocks
    {
        public class NormalClock
        {
            private Label label;

            public NormalClock(Label label)
            {
                if(label == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullReferenceException("label");

                this.label = label;
                label.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is not a good idea to let the clock know about the form. A clock should do clock things, not form things.

There are different ways of solving the problem. First, how does the clock tick? You will need a timer which generates tick events. Either this timer is in the form. Then the clock is only reading the current time and returns a string representing the time. The form then asks the clock for this string.

Another way which seems to better realize the idea of a clock, is to have a timer inside the clock. Now, how does the timer communicate the time to the form? Again, I see two possibilities. Either the clock itself exposes an event and provides a time string as event argument, or the clock writes the string to the form. But we don't want the latter, as explained above.

Since you want to create different types of clocks, first write a clock base class, that does everything but formatting the time string. The classes deriving from the base class then provide different kinds of time strings.

```
abstract class ClockBase
{
    private Timer _timer = new Timer(); // Create the timer.

    public event EventHandler<ClockTickEventArgs> Tick;

    public ClockBase()
    {
        _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick; // Subscribe to timer tick event.
        _timer.Interval = 1000; // Let the clock tick every 1000 ms.
        _timer.Start(); // Start the timer.
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string timeString = FormatTime(DateTime.Now); // Format the current date time.
        Tick?.Invoke(this, new ClockTickEventArgs(timeString)); // Fire the Tick event.
    }

    // This will be implemented by concrete clocks.
    protected abstract string FormatTime(DateTime time);
}
```

The normal clock derives from `ClockBase` and implements a way of formatting the time.

```
class NormalClock : ClockBase
{
    protected override string FormatTime(DateTime time)
    {
        return time.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
    }
}
```

The Form the does this:

```
public partial class frmClock : Form
{
    private ClockBase _clock;

    public frmClock()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _clock = new NormalClock(); // Create a normal clock.
        _clock.Tick += Clock_Tick; // Subscribe to the clock Tick event.
    }

    private void Clock_Tick(object sender, ClockTickEventArgs e)
    {
        lblTime.Text = e.TimeString; // Set the label text.
    }
}
```

We need one more thing: the class used as argument for the clock tick event:

```
class ClockTickEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ClockTickEventArgs(string timeString)
    {
        this.TimeString = timeString;
    }

    public string TimeString { get; private set; }
}
```

Now the clock does clock things and the form does display things.